# ElasticSearch - [nested] failed to find nested object under path

Tags: elasticsearch

I've a problem with my ElasticSearch query.
I'm trying to have a depart at one specific date, and a depart confirmed.

Here's a part of my template:

```
"mappings" : {
    "properties" : {
      "dates_depart" : {
        "type" : "nested",
        "properties": {
          "date_depart": {"type": "date"
          },
          "last_minute": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "depart_confirm": {
            "type": "integer"
          }
        }
      },
    }
}
```

Here's my query:

```
"query": { "nested" : { "path" : "dates_depart", "query" : { "bool" : { "must" : [ { "match" : {"dates_depart.depart_confirme" : 1}}, { "range" : {"dates_departs.date_depart" : {"gte":"07\/11\/2018","lte":"15\/11\/2018","format":"dd\/MM\/yyyy"}} }]}}}}
```

But my query returns this instead of 8 results:

```
"caused_by":{"type":"illegal_state_exception","reason":"[nested] nested object under path [dates_depart] is not of nested type"}}},"status":400}
```

How can I solve?

Comment: The error is pretty clear, the mapping you think you have is not the one that is installed in ES (i.e. `dates_depart` is not nested). What do you get when running `curl -XGET localhost:9200/your-index` ?

Answer (score -1):

Thin ... the last version of the template was not taken into account ...
I just corrected thanks.

Unfortunately, now I have a new mistake. Certainly linked to my index

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"json_e_o_f_exception","reason":"Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@67a98c0c; line: 1, column: 1])\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@67a98c0c; line: 1, column: 533]"}],"type":"json_e_o_f_exception","reason":"Unexpected end-of-input: expected close marker for Object (start marker at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@67a98c0c; line: 1, column: 1])\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@67a98c0c; line: 1, column: 533]"},"status":500}
```